# How to access hperledger composer REST api through angular 4 web application

Tags: angular, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Currently we are creating web application using angular 4 and hyperledger composer. The REST server is enabled with google oAuth authentication. And have done all the settings related to it on https://console.developers.google.com/

The scenario is user will login with its own gmail account and should be able to access REST api of the hyperledger composer. 
Basically performing this tutorial with web application https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest.

But the problem is when user logged in through web browser using angular web application, we get the token from google but i'm not able to access any REST api. It runs perfectly fine on  http://localhost:3000 . But when i try it from web application or through postman it doesn't work at all..

Does anybody have performed or did such type of user login authentication for hyperledger composer?

Answer (score 1):

From your Angular client (ie authenticated client) you would need to ensure the `withCredentials` option is set,  in-order to create a cookie to pass the authentication token to the REST server.

eg

```
headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/wallet/import', formData, {withCredentials: true, headers}).toPromise();
```

Now the client is authenticated with the REST server and an identity has been added to the wallet (via import) the business network endpoints can now be called: eg calling a query or a /GET - some examples below:

```
return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/queries/myQuery', {withCredentials: true}).toPromise();

return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/Commodity', {withCredentials: true}).toPromise();

this.http.get('http://mydomain:3000/api/MyAsset', { withCredentials: true })
```

Comment: I have used gapi/auth2 at client side. We are getting access token in an object and when we logged in to google we get json containing these parameters-
{ issued_to, audience, user_id, scope, expires_in, email, verified_email, access_type } 
And we need to pass the access_token right ?

And we are validating token using this link https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= "ACCESS TOKEN"

Comment: So my question is how to convert this object into the format which will be compatible for cookie. I tried encodeURIComponent() for this but its not working. The format which I checked on hyperledger composer REST server is different. The cookie contains UserId and access token and one more parameter is there but im not able to recognise it. So how can I get that format? 

So can you please help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate your angular app by using:

```
 <a id="googleLogin" href="http://domain:3000/auth/google">Log In</a>
```

This authenticates the user with the composer rest api and sets the session cookies in the browser.

Now if you hit the wallet api with {withCreditails:true} then it works.

```
this.http.get('http://domain:3000/api/wallet', { withCredentials: true })
```

For Logout:

```
<a id="googleLogin" href="domain:3000/auth/logout/auth/logout" (click)='logout()'>Logout</a>
```

For accessing the User profile of the logged in user, use gapi with same ClientID but use it just for init() and attaching listeners. Don't signin or signout through gapi.

I implemented this solution and work just fine.

```js
declare
const gapi: any;
googleUser: any;
public auth2: any;
private clientId: string = 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';
private scope = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
].join(' ');

public googleInit() {
  if (gapi) {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: this.clientId,
        scope: this.scope
      });
      this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleLogin'));
      this.init();
    });
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.googleInit();
    }, 500);
  }
}

public attachSignin(element) {
  this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
    (googleUser) => {
      let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
      console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
      // ...
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    });
}

init() {
  this.auth2.isSignedIn.listen(this.signinChanged);
  this.auth2.currentUser.listen(this.userChanged);
  this.refreshValues();
}

signinChanged = (val) => {
  console.log('google ### signinChanged', val);
}
/**
 * Listener method for when the user changes.
 *
 * @param {GoogleUser} user the updated user.
 */
userChanged = (user) => {
  console.log('google ### User now: ', user);
  this.googleUser = user;
  this.updateGoogleUser();
};

updateGoogleUser() {
  console.log('google ### user', this.googleUser);
  if (this.googleUser && this.googleUser.w3 && this.googleUser.Zi) {
    let userProfile: UserProfile = {
      id: this.googleUser.El,
      name: this.googleUser.w3.ig,
      email: this.googleUser.w3.U3,
      image: this.googleUser.w3.Paa,
      token: this.googleUser.Zi.access_token,
      idToken: this.googleUser.Zi.id_token,
      provider: this.googleUser.Zi.idpId
    }
    localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(userProfile));
  }
}

refreshValues = () => {
  if (this.auth2) {
    console.log('google ### Refreshing values...');

    this.googleUser = this.auth2.currentUser.get();

    this.updateGoogleUser();
  }
}
logout() {
  this.auth2.signOut();
}
```